# Django URL syntax ?P<slug>[^\\.]

Tags: django-urls

In this Django URL, what does the `?P<slug>[^\\.]` syntax mean?

```
url( r'^view/(?P<slug>[^\\.]+)/$', 'blog.views.view_post',  name='view_blog_post')),
```

Answer (score 2):

In python regex, `(?P<name>regex)` called  named capturing group

So `(?P<slug>[^\\.]+)` this would capture any character but not of a backslash or dot one or more times and store the matches inside the group name `slug`.

Then you may refer the captured chars by specifying it's index number or group name.